# WP Query get posts by specific author IDs if one of several logged in authors

Tags: wp-query, author

I have a custom template page where posts are shown from authors 1,2 and 3.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-5&author=1,2,3' ); ?>
```

How can I use **get current user** in this so that the posts are only visible to an author with one of those ID's (1,2 or 3) and are logged in?

In other words: Author 4 will not see any posts. Authors 1,2,3 will see each others posts if they are currently logged in.

Thanks very much in advance-

Comment: Please share the codes you have been trying to get this thing work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly something along these lines should work.

```
$authors = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // privileged users array
$signed_in_user = wp_get_current_user(); // get current user

// check if singed in user is in authors array
if ( in_array( $signed_in_user->ID, $authors ) ) {
    $query = array(
         'posts_per_page' = -1,
         'author__in' = $authors
     );
}
else {
     // alternate query for other users
}

$posts = new WP_Query( $query );
```

Comment: Hi @JoeyYax- Thanks for the help. Could you tell me how I would incorporate your code into mine? My skills are very limited. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/54DFM0aG

Comment: This should do the job: https://gist.github.com/joeyyax/cc79cac6aa86eb2d9809 - for a more detailed view of the changes: https://gist.github.com/joeyyax/cc79cac6aa86eb2d9809/revisions

Comment: Joey, thank you SO much for your time. However, I get parse error syntax error on this line: `if ( in_array( $signed_in_user->ID ), $authors ) {`

Comment: Sorry about that. I somehow put the closing `)` in the wrong place. I updated the gist here: https://gist.github.com/joeyyax/cc79cac6aa86eb2d9809

Comment: Joey, thank you very, very much. It works great. I REALLY appreciate the help :)